# What is the equivalent Main method for Java in c#

Tags: c#, java, runas, main-method

in
Java, you can write:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) { }
```

and than "right click" =>  "run as" => "Java application" and it will run the current Main Method.

Any chance to have that in Visual Web Developer?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Web Developer is presumably for *web* applications. Web applications don't run in that sort of way - they respond to web requests.

The equivalent of a `main` method (note case) in Java is a `Main` method in C#, in one of the following forms:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
static void Main()
static int Main(string[] args)
static int Main()
```

The method can have any accessibility, can return `int` or `void`, and either be parameterless or take an array of strings.

That will work fine when creating a console or Windows application - but *not* a web application. If you want to write desktop applications, use Visual C# Express or something similar.

Comment: So Do you have any idea Y can't I create a command line project in c# inside the VWD for testing? thanks

Comment: @SexyMF: The clue is in the name: *Visual Web Developer*. It's for developing *web* applications. Just install Visual C# Express as well.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot run functions from visual c# express that are located in VWD...

Comment: @SexyMF: You should be able to create a class library and use that from both environments. Ultimately, if you want to do everything you should probably just buy Visual Studio...

Comment: @SexyMF: Yes, within VS you can create all kinds of projects. Whether you can add a reference from a console app to code in a web app, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. Architecture of web-app is somewhat different then desktop or standalone applications.